# Reading values from text file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file with parameters and values such as

```
param1=value1;
param2=value2;
....
paramn=valuen;
```

Each of these params corresponding to `CheckBox` and each value to it's `Checked` state.

After i read file with `StreamReader` how should i perform assigning of values to Checkboxes ?

Comment: value could be true/false or 1/0 / or something an other?

Comment: true/false but there are few numeric values from comboBoxes and textBoxes. I want l33t way to get those without many lookups

Comment: I'm not stuck i want help with logic. How do i extract value for certain checkBox?

Comment: Is this winforms or asp.net application?

Comment: WinForms, does this matter in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a `Dictionary<string, CheckBox>` where the param name in the file corresponds to the checkbox. This way you could fill the checkboxes with some kind of linq query:

```
Dictionary<string, CheckBox> myCheckBoxes = new Dictionary<string, CheckBox>();

string path = @"C:\MyFile.txt";

var query = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
            let values = line.Split('=')
            select new { Key = values[0], Value = Boolean.Parse(values[1]) });

foreach (var kvp in query)
{
    myCheckBoxes[kvp.Key].Checked = kvp.Value;
}
```

Comment: I like this code because at the end it makes sense with such Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this approach:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           string[] lineValues = line.Split('=');

           // here is up to you how to find the control to set and to assign the value.
        }
    }
```

of course if you have to parse or do some mapping to identify which control needs to be set, I have not included it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Read file with `File.ReadAllLines()`
2. Parse every single line with `line.Split("=")` getting name (index 0) and value (index 1). 
   Here you can convert true/false (strings) to boolean values
3. Put every name/value in a `List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>` so you can use appropriate methods to retrieve (search) the key (checkbox name) and set its value. For example if you wanto to set *chk1* value you could use `lk.Find(item => item.Key == "chk1")).Value`

Using this method you could use a

```
foreach (ComboBox cb in ....)
{
    cb.Checked = lk.Find(item => item.Key == cb.Name)).Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the <s>l33t</s> best way is true/false, this way you can recognize bools from ints when you read the file. In your code it just doesn't matter because asking this question costs 100 times as much time as implementing any of the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You check a string value i.e., only with `"True"` from the text file after reading using `StreamReader`. If the `string.ToLower()` equals `"true"` then only check the checkbox in all remaining cases uncheck the corresponding checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

data.txt

```
param1=false;
param2=true;
```

code

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");

foreach (string current in data)
{
    string[] currDataArray = current.Trim(';').Split(new[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
    chb.Text = currDataArray[0];
    chb.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(currDataArray[1]);

    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("yourFilePath");
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
   string p = sr.ReadLine();
   string []param = p.Split('=', ';');
   CheckBox cb = Controls[param[0]] as CheckBox;
   if(cb != null)
       cb.Checked = Boolean.Parse(param[1]);
}
```